# ¿Como validar los datos de un json al deserealizar?

Tags: c#, json

Tengo una funcion que recibe un string ,el string es un json,
En la cual necesito validar los datos del json que me envian a la funcion ,este es mi json ,hay un array llamado productos ojo.

```
   {"comprobante_tipo":1,"comprobante_emision":"10-05-2017","comprobante_moneda":2,"documento_tipo":6,"documento_numero":"20536161199","direccion":"Av.La Tienda de Charlie","nombre":"Cesar Vallejo","productos":[{"nombre":"Caramelos2","codigo":741,"cantidad":12,"unidad":"2","precio_unidad":2000},{"nombre":"Chocolates2","codigo":231,"cantidad":12,"unidad":"UNIDADES","precio_unidad":20002}]}
```

Queria primero desearelizar el json,y ponerlo en un dynamic ,luego validarlo,y si estaba todo "bien",lo serealizo y lo envio a una webservice.
Pero al intentar el codigo de abajo me sale que debo aplicar un puntero.

```
   if (x->comprobante_moneda.GetType() == typeof(int)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Moneda"); }
```

Pasa con este ,y con el siguiente

```
if (x.comprobante_tipo.GetType() == typeof(int)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Tipo de Comprobante "); }
        if (x.comprobante_emision.GetType() == typeof(string)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Emision"); }
        if (x.documento_tipo.GetType() == typeof(int)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Tipo de Documento"); }
        if (x.documento_numero.GetType() == typeof(string)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Numero de Documento"); }
        if (x.direccion.GetType() == typeof(string)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Direccion"); }
        if (x.nombre.GetType() == typeof(string)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Nombre"); }
        if (x.productos.codigo.GetType() == typeof(string)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Productos"); }
        if (x.productos.cantidad.GetType() == typeof(int)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Cantidad"); }
        if (x.productos.unidad.GetType() == typeof(int)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Unidad"); }
        if (x.productos.precio_unidad.GetType() == typeof(int)) { } else { throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Precio de unidad"); }
```

Que podria hacer ? o que otra cosa deberia intentar? 
Gracias

Comment: Usas `x->comprobante_moneda` con flecha y abajo usas `x.comprobante_tipo` con punto. Como el error dice que debes aplicar un puntero, me parece que necesitas usar la flecha en vez de el punto. Por ejemplo, `x->comprobante_tipo.GetType()`

Comment: Tambien sucede con "->"

Comment: ¿Probaste cambiando todos los `x.` a `x->`? ¿El error te da la línea en el código donde ocurrió el error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo ideal es que serialices a una clase, aunque depende mucho de lo que te refieras con *validar*, es decir, que los enteros sean mayor a cero, cadenas de texto sin caracteres especiales etc. Con esto, estarías accediendo y evaluando de forma directa las propiedades de la clase.

Definición de clases:

```
public class Datos
{
    public int comprobante_tipo { get; set; }
    public string comprobante_emision { get; set; }
    public int comprobante_moneda { get; set; }
    public int documento_tipo { get; set; }
    public string documento_numero { get; set; }
    public string direccion { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public List<Productos> productos { get; set; }
}

public class Productos
{
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public int codigo { get; set; }
    public int cantidad { get; set; }
    public string unidad { get; set; }
    public decimal precio_unidad { get; set; }
}
```

Recibir el json y serializarlo al tipo `Datos`:

```
Datos datos = new Datos();
datos = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datos>(json);
```

Ahora, podras realizar todas las validaciones necesarias sobre el objeto `datos`. Por ejemplo:

```
if(datos.comprobante_tipo == 0)
{
    throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Tipo de Comprobante ");
}
```

Para realizar validaciones en la lista, se tiene que recorrer usando `foreach`:

```
foreach(Productos item in datos.productos) { 
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.nombre)) {
        throw new Exception("Ingreso no Valido en Nombre"); }
    }
}
```

Comment: ESO !! GRACIAS! validar que sean int ,string ,algo asi jajaja gracias

Comment: Una pregunta,como haría cuando llegue a productos?
        if(datos.productos.comprobante_tipo == 0)
 asi?

Comment: Con `foreach(Productos item in datos.productos) { }` de momento no podría actualizar la respuesta pero en cuanto pueda pongo esta parte de código :)

Comment: Muchas gracias,ya lo resolvi con el foreach que acabas de publicar en un rato subire el codigo por si alguien tiene este problema .Gracias! ;D

Comment: @francovargas actualicé la respuesta con el código de foreach :)